# How to have one java thread wait for the result of another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I frequently need to have a thread wait for the result of another thread.  Seems like there should be some support for this in java.util.concurrent, but I can't find it.

[Exchanger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) is very close to what I'm talking about, but it's bi-directional.  I only want Thread A to wait on Thread B, not have both wait on each other.

Yes, I know I can use a CountDownLatch or a Semaphore or Thread.wait() and then manage the result of the computation myself, but it seems like I must be missing a convenience class somewhere.

What am I missing?

*UPDATE*

```
// An Example which works using Exchanger
// but you would think there would be uni-directional solution
protected Exchanger<Integer> exchanger = new Exchanger<Integer>();

public void threadA() {
    // perform some computations
    int result = ...;

    exchanger.exchange(result);
}


public void threadB() {

    // retrieve the result of threadA
    int resultOfA = exchanger.exchange(null);
}
```

Comment: Can you lock the resource? It will block the calling thread until the first one unlock the resource. There is a lot of thing you can do with it : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

Comment: Another problem with Exchanger is that it only works with a **pair of threads**. With Exchanger, it is not possible to have multiple threads waiting for the value to be set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, it seems like [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) may be the best solution I've found.

eg.

```
BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1);
```

The waiting thread will call `queue.take()` to wait for the result, and the producing queue will call `queue.add()` to submit the result.

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for [`Future<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)? That's the normal representation of a task which has (usually) been submitted to a work queue, but may not have completed yet. You can find out its completion status, block until it's finished, etc.

Look at [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for the normal way of obtaining futures. Note that this is focused on getting the result of an individual *task*, not rather than waiting for a *thread* to finish. A single thread may complete many tasks in its life time, of course - that's the whole point of a thread pool.

Comment: The problem with Future is that I would need to also use CountdownLatch or some other synchronization mechanism to manage when the result is available.  It ends up being a lot more code (I believe) than just using an Exchanger

Comment: @emmby: Why would you need to do that? If you're happy blocking, just call `future.get()` from the consuming thread. Add a timeout if you want. It's not clear why that wouldn't work for you... The only problem is if the thread producing the value is still meant to keep doing something else... you haven't made the bigger picture terribly clear.

Comment: Hi Jon, I updated the question with an example that hopefully demonstrates what I'm talking about.

Comment: @emmby: Well that looks like it would be fine with a future. Instead of explicitly setting the value, you'd return it from a `Callable<T>` implementation which would have been submitted to an executor service and wrapped in a `Future<T>`.

Comment: I don't disagree it could be done.  You don't think the Exchanger or the BlockingQueue solution is less verbose and easier to understand though?

Comment: @emmby: It's hard to say from the limited context you've given us. How are you starting the thread, for example? Is it started from thread A? `Future<T>` is pretty much the standard way of representing a task which will return a value when it's finished though.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over either of the thread lifecycles.

Comment: @emmby: So you don't have control over how the threads are created? That would indeed prevent you from really using `Future<T>` effectively. Shame, as that's the most idiomatic approach :(

Answer (score 4):

The JDK doesn't provide a convenience class that provides the exact functionality you're looking for. However, it is actually fairly easy to write a small utility class to do just that.

You mentioned the CountDownLatch and your preference regarding it, but I would still suggest looking at it. You can build a small utility class (a "value synchronizer" if you will) pretty easily:

```
public class OneShotValueSynchronizer<T> {
    private volatile T value;
    private final CountDownLatch set = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public T get() throws InterruptedException {
        set.await();
        return value;
    }

    public synchronized void set(T value) {
        if (set.getCount() > 0) {
            this.value = value;
            set.countDown();
        }
    }

    // more methods if needed
}
```

Comment: That's the sort of class I was looking for, thank you.  It's a little surprising there isn't one like it already.

Comment: You would think that they would have provided one like this, and I was surprised too. I guess it was left to the users as an exercise? :)

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 8 you can use [`CompletableFuture<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). Thread A can wait for a result using the blocking `get()` method, while Thread B can pass the result of computation using `complete()`.

If Thread B encounters an exception while calculating the result, it can communicate this to Thread A by calling `completeExceptionally()`.

Answer (score 0):

What's inconvenient in using `Thread.join()`?

Comment: I think he wants to wait for a Thread to modify a value not for a Thread to finish his job, no?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem, tried using a Future then a CountdownLatch but settled on an Exchanger. They are supposed to allow two threads to swap data but there's no reason why one of those threads can't just pass a null.

In the end I think it was the cleanest solution, but it may depend on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That's exactly the same situation I found myself in.  Glad to hear it's not just me.  Right now I'm trying to decide whether BlockingQueue or Exchanger (or maybe something else) is the cleanest paradigm

Answer (score 0):

You might use java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch for this.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Example:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

// thread one
// do some work
latch.countDown();

// thread two
latch.await();
```

Comment: I suspect the OP is already aware of that: "Yes, I know I can use a CountDownLatch or ..."

Comment: 'Yes, I know I can use a CountDownLatch or a Semaphore or Thread.wait() and then manage the result of the computation myself, but it seems like I must be missing a convenience class somewhere.'